# Read local .csv into spark scala 2.12.12 using IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to import a comma delimited `.csv` file into a Scala project with version 2.12.12 using IntelliJ. I have been unsuccessful at importing this file. The file has 1 million rows and 5 columns. In addition to importing and reading the file, I also have to find the total by month in the data.

I have tried:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:\Users\trialrun\Desktop\DataExtract.csv")
```

Spark throws an error: `not found: value df`

I have tried this as well and get the same error:

```
df = spark.read.csv("file:///C:\\Users\trialrun\Desktop\DataExtract.csv").show()
```

My `build.sbt` is successful and I have created an object in IntelliJ to try and read my csv file from my desktop, but, I need help with the correct dependencies to import and the correct logic to get IntelliJ to read the `.csv` file with headers from my desktop.

Comment: Have you installed Spark correctly? Are you using a Spark that is compatible with winutils and hadoop `dll` file?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out my issue.  I created another spark scala project and used version 2.11.11 with dependencies 2.1.0 for spark-core and spark-sql.  After refreshing the .sbt, all of the right dependencies were added and all of my errors were gone.  I was able to load the csv file.